# Сводная таблица с текстом в области значений

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Друзья, добрый день.
Пытаюсь сделать сводную таблицу, в которой в области значений будет текст, но пока не хватает опыта. Решить с помощью доп. столбца - не вариант, т.к. надо будет прописывать формулу в каждой ячейке, а их предполагается много и ожидается торможение книги. Создать сводную таблицу средствами таблиц гугл, равно как и создать сводную через QUERY & PIVOT не получается, т.к. текст в области данных либо не отображается, либо не воспринимается вообще. Может, кто-то уже решал подобную задачу - поделитесь красивым решением. пожалуйста! [Пример тут](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O6iP43VkAjG3huqWCn8Imf9ZxpaAtJgi6ekV1lUl8Oo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Это не подойдет? Сводная таблица с текстом в значениях: https://www.planetaexcel.ru/techniques/8/1640/

Comment: Глеб, благодарю. Подойдёт, но подобный вариант я использовал. Хотелось бы одной функцией заполнить все ячейки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение!
Для таблицы с примером

```
=ArrayFormula(ВПР(E3:E14&F2:H2;{$A$3:$A&$B$3:$B\C3:C};2;0))
```